# Sum of array inclusive of (0,L) with condition A[i] > A[R]

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

#### You are given an array A of length N. You are asked Q queries.

#### Each query is of the form `L, R`. and the answer is the sum of `A[i]` for all i such that `0 <= i <= L` and `A[i] > A[R]`.

I have tried Binary Tree and brute force, but it complexity is high (got TLE). Also use Mo' Algo but got stuck.

### CONSTRAINS

```
1 ≤ N,Q ≤ 10**5
1 ≤ A[i] ≤ 10**5
0 ≤ L,R < N
```

TEST CASE

```
(N) 4 
(A) 6 7 2 5 
(Q) 2 2
    3 1
```

OUTPUT

`13 0`

I want to know how can I effectively use Mo' Algorithm or Segment tree for such problem.

Is there any other data Structre to use.

Comment: Can the queries be sorted? Do you have a link to the problem?

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/competitive/december-circuits-23/algorithm/curious-queries-112c4758/

Answer (score 2):

If the queries are provided offline, we can do this with a Fenwick tree in `O(n log n)` time and `O(n)` space. Order the queries by ascending values of `A[R]`. As we progress, less elements in the array will be relevant to the sum.

Create a sorted list of the array's values that can also provide their original indexes.

Create a Fenwick tree that can sum segments of a list and insert the whole array. Before each query, continue traversing the sorted list and set to 0 in the Fenwick tree each element that's smaller than or equal to the current `A[R]`. Then output the sum between `0` and `L`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an online algorithm that takes `O(N log(N))` data and time `O(N log(N) + Q log^2(n))`.

What we do is build a data structure for each column, then for the pairs, then quadruplets etc that allows the lookup within that range of columns by a binary search. In your case with an array of `[6, 7, 2, 5]` that data structure will look like:

```
sum_at = [
    [   # columns.
        [(6, 6)],
        [(7, 7)],
        [(2, 2)],
        [(5, 5)]
    ],
    [    # pairs of columns
        [(6, 13), (7, 7)],
        [(2, 7), (5, 5)]
    ],
    [    # quadruplets of columns
         [(2, 20), (5, 18), (6, 13), (7, 7)]
    ]]
```

The first level of this data structure can be built by just remapping the values into columns. The other levels can be built by merging pairs of columns. Here is code to do that.

```
def build_search (a):
    last_sum = [[(v, v)] for v in a]
    sum_at = [last_sum]
    while 1 < len(last_sum):
        next_sum = []
        k = 0
        while 2*k < len(last_sum):
            stack1 = last_sum[2*k]
            if 2*k+1 < len(last_sum):
                stack2 = last_sum[2*k+1]
            else:
                stack2 = []
            i = j = 0
            col = []
            while i < len(stack1) and j < len(stack2):
                if stack1[i][0] < stack2[j][0]:
                    col.append((stack1[i][0], stack1[i][1] + stack2[j][1]))
                    i += 1
                elif stack2[j][0] < stack1[i][0]:
                    col.append((stack2[j][0], stack1[i][1] + stack2[j][1]))
                    j += 1
                else:
                    col.append((stack1[i][0], stack1[i][1] + stack2[j][1]))
                    i += 1
                    j += 1
            while i < len(stack1):
                col.append(stack1[i])
                i += 1
            while j < len(stack2):
                col.append(stack2[j])
                j += 1
            next_sum.append(col)
            k += 1
        last_sum = next_sum
        sum_at.append(last_sum)
    return sum_at
```

How does this help us? Well:

- A lookup for `L = 0` just needs `sum_at[0][0]` because that is column 0.
- A lookup for `L = 1` just needs `sum_at[1][0]` because that has columns 0 and 1.
- A lookup for `L = 2` combines `sum_at[0][2]` (for column 2) and `sum_at[1][0]` (for columns 0 and 1)..
- A lookup for `L = 3` just needs `sum_at[2][0]` because that has columns 0, 1, 2, and 3.

Where "just needs" means that you can do a binary search inside that chunk of `sum_at` to find the sum across a group of columns of everything above the desired value.

And the logic for which values to look for is as follows. If you're looking for column `i` in group `j` and `i` is even, you can just look at that column. Otherwise you can cut `i` in half, and skip up one level to look at that column and the previous. Then after you look

```
def search (sum_at, l, r):
    # The first layer of sum_at includes the values.
    value = sum_at[0][r][0][0]
    # i will be the column.
    i = l
    # j will be the layer
    j = 0

    answer = 0
    while -1 < i:
        while 1 == i % 2:
            i = i // 2
            j += 1
        col = sum_at[j][i]

        # binary search.
        # The range is 0 (all elements in sum) to off the end end of the array (no elements in sum).
        k_lower = 0
        k_upper = len(col)
        # This gets it down to 2 values.
        while k_lower + 1 < k_upper:
            # Average rounding down to guarantee not looking off end of array
            k = (k_lower + k_upper) // 2
            # Is this value too big?
            if value < col[k][0]:
                k_upper = k
            else:
                k_lower = k

        # We've narrowed it down to k_lower or k_upper.
        # Test them.
        if value < col[k_lower][0]:
            answer += col[k_lower][1]
        elif k_upper < len(col):
            answer += col[k_upper][1]

        # Now get earlier columns.
        i = i - 1
    return answer
```

And here is a simple test.

```
a = [6, 7, 2, 5]
sum_at = build_search(a)

for l in range(len(a)):
    for r in range(len(a)):
        print(l, r, search(sum_at, l, r))
```

(If I understand the problem correctly, all gave correct answers.)

Answer (score 0):

### FINALLY SOLVED IT

#### Thanks All

```
from math import ceil,log2

def merge(left_val, right_val):
    result = Item()
    n = len(left_val.array)
    m = len(right_val.array)
    
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < n and j < m:
        if left_val.array[i]  >= right_val.array[j]:
            result.array.append(left_val.array[i])
            i +=1
        else:
            result.array.append(right_val.array[j])
            j +=1
    
    while i < n:
        result.array.append(left_val.array[i])
        i +=1
    
    while j < m:
        result.array.append(right_val.array[j])
        j +=1
    
    
    for i in range(len(result.array)):
        if i == 0:
            result.total.append(result.array[i])
        else:
            result.total.append(result.total[-1] + result.array[i])
        
    return result
    
    
class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []
        self.total = []
        
class SegmentTree:
    def __init__(self,input_list):
        self._input_list = input_list[:]
        self._init_tree()
    
    def _init_tree(self):
        # length of list
        self.n = len(self._input_list)
        
        # calc. height
        height = ceil(log2(self.n))
        
        n_nodes = 2* (2 ** height) - 1
        
        self._seg_tree = [Item() for _ in range(n_nodes)]
      
        arr_left = 0
        arr_right = self.n - 1
        seg_node_index = 0
        self._propogate(arr_left,arr_right,seg_node_index)
        
    def _propogate(self,arr_left, arr_right, seg_node_index):
        # recursive
        # base case
        if arr_right < arr_left:
            return 
        if arr_left == arr_right:
            self._seg_tree[seg_node_index].array.append(self._input_list[arr_left])
            self._seg_tree[seg_node_index].total.append(self._input_list[arr_left])
            return
        
        midpoint = (arr_left + arr_right) // 2 
        
        left_seg_node_index = seg_node_index * 2 + 1
        left_node_arr_left = arr_left
        left_node_arr_right = midpoint
        
        self._propogate(left_node_arr_left,left_node_arr_right,left_seg_node_index)
        
        right_seg_node_index = seg_node_index * 2 + 2
        right_node_arr_left = midpoint + 1
        right_node_arr_right = arr_right
        
        self._propogate(right_node_arr_left,right_node_arr_right,right_seg_node_index)
        
        left_val = self._seg_tree[left_seg_node_index]
        right_val = self._seg_tree[right_seg_node_index]
        
        self._seg_tree[seg_node_index] = merge(left_val,right_val)
        
    def query(self, query_left, query_right, target_index):
        arr_left = 0
        arr_right = self.n - 1
        seg_node_index = 0
        target = self._input_list[target_index]
        
        return self._query(query_left, query_right, arr_left, arr_right, seg_node_index, target)
        
        
        
    def _query(self,query_left, query_right, arr_left, arr_right, seg_node_index, target):
        # recursive
        # base case
        if arr_right < arr_left:
            return 0
            
        if  query_right < arr_left or arr_right < query_left:
            # outside the range
            return 0
            
        if query_left <= arr_left and arr_right <= query_right: # complete inside the range
            i, idx = 0, -1
            j = len(self._seg_tree[seg_node_index].array) - 1
            
            while i <= j:
                midpoint = (i + j) // 2 
                if self._seg_tree[seg_node_index].array[midpoint] > target:
                    idx = midpoint
                    i = midpoint + 1
                else:
                    j = midpoint - 1
            if idx != -1:
                return self._seg_tree[seg_node_index].total[idx]
                
            return 0
        
        midpoint = (arr_left + arr_right) // 2
        left_seg_node_index = seg_node_index * 2 + 1
        left_node_arr_left = arr_left
        left_node_arr_right = midpoint
        
        left_val = self._query(query_left, query_right, left_node_arr_left, left_node_arr_right, left_seg_node_index,target)
        
        right_seg_node_index = seg_node_index * 2 + 2
        right_node_arr_left = midpoint + 1
        right_node_arr_right = arr_right
        
        right_val = self._query(query_left, query_right, right_node_arr_left, right_node_arr_right, right_seg_node_index, target)
        print(left_val,right_val)
        return left_val + right_val
        
a = [6,7,2,5]
seg = SegmentTree(a)
        
print(seg.query(0,2,2))
print(seg.query(0,3,1))
```